# How do I compile mod_dontdothat on Windows

Tags: svn, apache

I cannot seem to compile mod_dontdothat on Windows. Has anybody managed to achieve this?

Edit:

I've tried compiling the file according to the readme on the site and I've tried to add extra libs to reduce the link errors. Ive got the following installed:

1. Apache 2.2.9
2. Visual Studio 2008
3. ActivePerl
4. apxs-win32 from ApacheLounge
5. Subversion libs and headers

I run the following command line:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin>apxs -c -I ..\include\
svn_config.h -L ..\lib -L C:\Progra~1\Micros~1.0\VC\lib -l apr-1.lib -l aprutil-
1.lib -l svn_subr-1.lib -l libapr-1.lib -l libaprutil-1.lib -l libhttpd.lib -l l
ibsvn_subr-1.lib -l mod_dav.lib mod_dontdothat.c
```

Then I get the following errors:

```
cl  /nologo /MD /W3 /O2 /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D NDEBUG    -I"C:\PROGRA~1\APACHE~
1\Apache2.2\include"  /I"..\include\svn_config.h"  /c /Fomod_dontdothat.lo mod_d
ontdothat.c
mod_dontdothat.c
link kernel32.lib /nologo /subsystem:windows /dll /machine:I386 /libpath:"C:\PRO
GRA~1\APACHE~1\Apache2.2\lib" /out:mod_dontdothat.so  /libpath:"..\lib"  /libpat
h:"C:\Progra~1\Micros~1.0\VC\lib"  apr-1.lib aprutil-1.lib svn_subr-1.lib libapr
-1.lib libaprutil-1.lib libhttpd.lib libsvn_subr-1.lib mod_dav.lib   mod_dontdot
hat.lo
   Creating library mod_dontdothat.lib and object mod_dontdothat.exp
mod_dontdothat.lo : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _dav_svn_split_uri
@32 referenced in function _is_this_legal
svn_subr-1.lib(io.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__libint
l_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(subst.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__lib
intl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(config_auth.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __im
p__libintl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(time.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__libi
ntl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(nls.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__libin
tl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(dso.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__libin
tl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(path.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__libi
ntl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(prompt.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__li
bintl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__lib
intl_dgettext referenced in function _print_error
svn_subr-1.lib(config.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__li
bintl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(utf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__libin
tl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(cmdline.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__l
ibintl_dgettext
svn_subr-1.lib(utf.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__libin
tl_sprintf referenced in function _fuzzy_escape
svn_subr-1.lib(path.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__libi
ntl_sprintf
svn_subr-1.lib(cmdline.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__l
ibintl_fprintf referenced in function _svn_cmdline_init
svn_subr-1.lib(config_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp
__SHGetFolderPathA@20 referenced in function _svn_config__win_config_path
svn_subr-1.lib(config_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp
__SHGetFolderPathW@20 referenced in function _svn_config__win_config_path
svn_subr-1.lib(config_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp
__RegCloseKey@4 referenced in function _svn_config__parse_registry
svn_subr-1.lib(config_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp
__RegEnumKeyExA@32 referenced in function _svn_config__parse_registry
svn_subr-1.lib(config_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp
__RegOpenKeyExA@20 referenced in function _svn_config__parse_registry
svn_subr-1.lib(config_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp
__RegQueryValueExA@24 referenced in function _parse_section
svn_subr-1.lib(config_win.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp
__RegEnumValueA@32 referenced in function _parse_section
svn_subr-1.lib(win32_xlate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __im
p__CoUninitialize@0 referenced in function _svn_subr__win32_xlate_open
svn_subr-1.lib(win32_xlate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __im
p__CoInitializeEx@8 referenced in function _svn_subr__win32_xlate_open
svn_subr-1.lib(win32_xlate.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __im
p__CoCreateInstance@20 referenced in function _get_page_id_from_name
svn_subr-1.lib(nls.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__libin
tl_bindtextdomain referenced in function _svn_nls_init
svn_subr-1.lib(stream.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflate
referenced in function _read_handler_gz
svn_subr-1.lib(stream.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateI
nit_ referenced in function _read_handler_gz
svn_subr-1.lib(stream.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflate
referenced in function _write_handler_gz
svn_subr-1.lib(stream.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateI
nit_ referenced in function _write_handler_gz
svn_subr-1.lib(stream.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflateE
nd referenced in function _close_handler_gz
svn_subr-1.lib(stream.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _inflateE
nd referenced in function _close_handler_gz
mod_dontdothat.so : fatal error LNK1120: 21 unresolved externals
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=6291456
.
```

I'm not too much of a C guru, so any help in finding these unresolved external symbols will be much appreciated!

Comment: I updated my answer according to your questions. The compile process uses libs from the svn package, from the apache package and some standard libs from visual studio. There is no secific version required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to compile the module. Prerequisites:

- Apache 2.2.11
- [apxs-win32](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/apxs_win32.zip) from www.apachelounge.com
- Visual Studio 2005
- [Active Perl 5.8.8](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/) (you need perl for apxs-win32 installation)

Here is a step-by-step guide.
Download these packages:

- http://subversion.tigris.org/files/documents/15/44595/svn-win32-1.5.5_dev.zip (we need the libraries and header files from this package)
- http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-1.5.5.zip (we will be using the `mod_dav_svn` sources to compile a static lib)

Unpack the dev package to `c:\temp\svn` and the other package to `c:\temp\svn-src` and the `mod_dontdothat` files to `C:\Temp\dontdothat`.

One of the dependencies of `mod_dontdothat` module is `mod_dav_svn` module. Unfortunately you'll find the `mod_dav_svn` binary only as a shared library (DLL). You cannot link against
a DLL. So the first step is to build a static `mod_dav_svn` library:

```
cd C:\Temp\svn-src\subversion\mod_dav_svn
apxs -c -I ..\include  -L C:\Temp\svn\lib -l libsvn_delta-1.lib -l libsvn_diff-1.lib -l libsvn_fs-1.lib -l libsvn_fs_base-1.lib -l libsvn_fs_fs-1.lib -l libsvn_fs_util-1.lib -l libsvn_repos-1.lib -l libsvn_subr-1.lib -l libapr-1.lib -l libaprutil-1.lib -l libhttpd.lib -l mod_dav.lib -l xml.lib  -n mod_dav_svn mod_dav_svn.c activity.c authz.c deadprops.c liveprops.c lock.c merge.c mirror.c repos.c util.c version.c reports\dated-rev.c reports\file-revs.c reports\get-locations.c reports\get-location-segments.c reports\get-locks.c reports\log.c reports\mergeinfo.c reports\replay.c reports\update.c
```

The apxs call will print the commands it executes. The last command is a link call which builds the DLL. Copy it replace "link" by "lib", remove the "/dll" param, and change the "out" param file name to "`libmod_dav_svn.lib`". You should get something similar to:

```
lib kernel32.lib /nologo /subsystem:windows /machine:I386 /libpath:"C:\PROGRA~1\APACHE~1\Apache2.2\lib" /out:libmod_dav_svn.lib  /libpath:"C:\Temp\svn\lib"  libsvn_delta-1.lib libsvn_diff-1.lib libsvn_fs-1.lib libsvn_fs_base-1.lib libsvn_fs_fs-1.lib libsvn_fs_util-1.lib libsvn_repos-1.lib libsvn_subr-1.lib libapr-1.lib libaprutil-1.lib libhttpd.lib mod_dav.lib xml.lib   reports\update.lo reports\replay.lo reports\mergeinfo.lo reports\log.lo reports\get-locks.lo reports\get-location-segments.lo reports\get-locations.lo reports\file-revs.lo reports\dated-rev.lo version.lo util.lo repos.lo mirror.lo merge.lo lock.lo liveprops.lo deadprops.lo authz.lo activity.lo mod_dav_svn.lo
```

You will get some link warnings. You can ignore them. Copy the `libmod_dav_svn.lib` to the `mod_dontdothat` directory. Now start the compilation process for `mod_dontdothat`:

```
C:\Temp\dontdothat
apxs -c -I C:\Temp\svn\include -L C:\Temp\svn\lib -l libsvn_subr-1.lib -l libapr-1.lib -l libaprutil-1.lib -l libhttpd.lib -l mod_dav.lib -l xml.lib -l libmod_dav_svn.lib    mod_dontdothat.c
apxs -i -n dontdothat mod_dontdothat.so
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: I like the step by step list! Two quick questions:
- Where did you get hold of apxs?
- Which version of lib are you using? Is it the one that comes with Visual Studio?

Comment: Thanks for adding all the prerequisites! This is really a high quality answer!

Answer (score 3):

Googling around I've got

- `mod_dav_svn.lib` for `_dav_svn_split_uri`
- `intl3_svn.lib` for all things `_libintl`
- `shell32.lib` for SHGetFolderPath
- `advapi32.lib` for `Reg`istry stuff
- `ole32.lib` for `CoInitialize` and it's ilk
- `inflate` and `deflate` smell like `zlib1.lib` or something like that

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for revising the question.

It looks like a definite linker issue.  I see that the first undefined symbol is related to webdav.  Are you sure you have that library in the right place?  I see you give a nice long path with lots of svn libs, maybe it's possible you overlooked just one?

Comment: Yep - I definitely overlooked some libs, but which ones?